# ConnectionAbortedError when the page's loading is canceled by the user (Python3 Quart)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, quart

The error `ConnectionAbortedError` is thrown if the page's loading is canceled when using a Python3 Quart webserver. Using `@app.errorhandler(ConnectionAbortedError)` with an appropriate function is completely ignored. How do I handle this error?

Edit - Minimal reproducible example:

```
import time, asyncio
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def send_to_channel():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 'hi'

asyncio.run(app.run_task('0.0.0.0', port=3000))
```

Comment: @MarceloPaco I only need to know how to handle this error in Quart, so I didn't think I would need to supply a reproducible example (because this problem is not specific to me).